# Converting .Htaccess Rewrite Rule to Nginx

Tags: nginx, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I have the following apache rewrite rule which I am trying to convert to work with nginx.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(.*)-(\d{4})(?:-(.*))?$ album.php?artist=$1&album=$2&releaseyear=$3&extra=$4
```

I would expect it to simply be

```
location / { 
    rewrite "^/(.*)\/(.*)-(\d{4})(?:-(.*))?$" /album.php?artist=$1&album=$2&releaseyear=$3&extra=$4; 
}
```

Although this is not working, are there any clear issues with the nginx version of my rewrite rule?

Comment: This sort of logic belongs in your application, not in the web server configuration. See [Front Controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern).